# where clause in mysql to include all and exclude a string

Tags: mysql

```
Select * from table where col1 <> 'R'
```

col1 has various values and also has NULL how to write the where statement which includes all also the NULL value except the 'R' string

Comment: ... `where col1 is null or col1<>'R'`

Comment: col1 has other values also

Comment: Yup - so you chose `null` (first part) **or** everything but 'R' (second part)

Comment: What is wring with your query could you provide example data where it doenn#t work

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from table where col1 <> 'R' OR col1 IS NULL
```

For get null value use IS NULL, if you also expect value of 'R', add col1 <> 'R'.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.